# Adding vectors using algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An airplane flying at 500 km North West encounters a wind of 120 km/h blowing in the direction 
W 25° S. Determine the actual velocity (ground velocity) of the plane.

I feel as if there's not enough information given in  the question, for example, I know the plane is flying North but I don't know how many degrees west.

Comment: Perhaps assume northwest means 45 degrees north of west

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they mean $\mathrm{NW} = 315$ degrees from north as it is usual in navigation and meteorology. Then, if the flying speed is $500 \, \mathrm{km}/\mathrm{h}$, the velocity vector can be defined as:

$$\mathbf{u} = 500 \, (-\cos{\pi/4} \, \mathbf{e}_x + \sin{\pi/4} \, \mathbf{e}_y),$$ where $\mathbf{e}_i$ are the unit vectors in the $x_i$ directions.

Can you take it from here?